# how to give $toObjectId in Java Mongo Projection Operation

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new bee to mongo. Below is the Aggregation operation I am doing in `mongodb` shell . But In my java ProjectionAggregation , am not able to give the `$toObjectId`. Please correct me what am I missing.

`db shell query`

```
 db.getCollection('UserData').aggregate([

{
 $project : {
     "username" : "$username",
     "beneficiaries" : "$beneficiaries"
        
     }   
 },
 {
    $unwind :   {
        path : "$beneficiaries",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
 $project : {  
     "username" : "$username",
     "beneficiaries" : "$beneficiaries",
      ---- dont know how to give $toObjectId in java ProjectionOperation .
     "beneficiaryStudId" : { $toObjectId : "$beneficiaries.studentId" }  
     }
 },
  {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "StudentProfileData",
           localField: "beneficiaryStudId",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "studProfile"
          }
      }
])
```

`Java code Projection Operation`

```
        ProjectionOperation projectUserAndBeneficiaries = Aggregation.project()
                  .andExpression("username").as("username")
                  .andExpression("beneficiaries").as("beneficiaries");

        
        ProjectionOperation projectUserAndOtherDetails = Aggregation.project()
                  .andExpression("username").as("username")
                  .andExpression("beneficiaries").as("beneficiaries")
---- How to give $toObjectId in projection operation             .andExpression("beneficiaries.studentId").as("beneficiaryStudId");
                  
        LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().
                from("StudentProfileData").
                localField("beneficiaryStudId").
                foreignField("_id").
                as("studProfile");
 
        Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(projectUserAndBeneficiaries, unwindBeneficiars,  
                projectUserAndOtherDetails
                ,lookupOperation);
        AggregationResults<UserAndStudentData> output 
          = mongotemplate.aggregate(agg, "UserData", UserAndStudentData.class);
```

Sample Ouput

```
Output in db shell
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d2f08574de2690001c281ac"),
    "username" : "ks241@goo.com",
    "beneficiaries" : {
        "studentId" : "5d2f0e9c3bcf3e0001a7e562",
        "mcBeneficiaryId" : "597418",
        "enabled" : true
    },
    "beneficiaryStudId" : ObjectId("5d2f0e9c3bcf3e0001a7e562"),
    "studProfile" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d2f0e9c3bcf3e0001a7e562"),
            "lastName" : "Sharma",
            "firstName" : "Kapil",
            "studentRegisterCustomFieldValues" : [ 
                {
                    "bcfdValue" : "One",
                    "bcfdName" : "Year"
                } 
            ],
            "gender" : "M",
            "merchantId" : "38788943"
        }
    ]
}
```

where as in **java**

the studProfile array is always empty if I add $toObjectId the above java aggregation projection query and ran it produces the values as same as that db shell .

Comment: Sorry  can you correct me If Im worng. You wanted add  the expected  output in the question . @Minsky

Comment: I don't know java, but from atlas it exports to this `Arrays.asList(project(computed("username", "$username"), computed("beneficiaries", "$beneficiaries"), computed("beneficiaryStudId", eq("$toObjectId", "$beneficiaries.studentId"))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring data doesn't support to few type of methods. This problem may include into it. But we may use this solution.

```
Aggregation aggregation=newAggregation(
    p-> new Document("$project",
        new Document()
        .append("username","$username"),
        .append("beneficiaries","$beneficiaries)
        .append("beneficiaryStudId",
            new Document("$toObjectId","$beneficiaries.studentId")
        )
     )
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this with Spring's `ProjectionOperation` and `ConvertOperators` classes:

```
ProjectionOperation projection = Aggregation.project()
        .andInclude("username", "beneficiaries")
        .and(ConvertOperators.ToObjectId.toObjectId("$beneficiaries.studentId"))
            .as("beneficiaryStudId");
```